# String Template - Results are different when Reading from File / Reading from String

Tags: c#, stringtemplate

```
string template = "group simple; apply(it) ::= << $it:bold():italics()$ >> ";
StringTemplateGroup stg = new StringTemplateGroup(new StringReader(template));
stg.DefineTemplate("bold", "<b>$it$</b>");
stg.DefineTemplate("italics", "<i>$it$</i>");
StringTemplate st = stg.GetInstanceOf("apply");
st.SetAttribute("it", "name");
Console.WriteLine(st.ToString());
```

The result of above is **$it:bold():italics()$** I was expecting `<i><b>name</b></i>`

But when the template is read from file, it works as expected.

```
StringTemplateGroup stg = new StringTemplateGroup("page", "../../Templates");
stg.DefineTemplate("bold", "<b>$it$</b>");
stg.DefineTemplate("italics", "<i>$it$</i>");
StringTemplate st = stg.GetInstanceOf("apply"); //apply.st => $it:bold():italics()$
st.SetAttribute("it", "name");
Console.WriteLine(st.ToString());
```

Output is as expected `<i><b>name</b></i>`

Why isn't it working in the first case? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

<...> is default delimiter in group files. Note StringTemplate v4 will be out in a week or so.

Comment: I had tried using <...> and the result was name:bold():italics().

Comment: oh. that's C# version; should work same, but...apparently not!